# Keyboard Pakages error

Tags: keyboard, 20.04

Mistakenly I deleted keyboard packages and now it is not working properly volume up is not working and volume down is working when i press any keys of 2nd part of keyboard it turns of auto  and when i release enter key it comes with the message of power off or not please help me how to restore it. It seems that keyboard error.I have tried all the ways from me please help me

Comment: Why not look in the package logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) to see what you removed, and re-install those packages?  If you removed them via command, your command `history` would likely be faster..  *Sorry, I have no idea what you removed, thus no idea how to reverse it, thus my suggestion to look into what you did.  If you need more, you'll need to wait for other suggestions*

Comment: ok please help as fast as possible